# How to add WMS to QGIS or any client

Tags: arcgis-server, rest

I'm trying to get this dataset. It's a bit confusing with the proxy on the front of it. Seems like QGIS does not like the domain infront of the ArcGIS Server.

http://gismaps.co.sangamon.il.us/tpv/proxy.ashx?http://Aberdeen/ArcGIS/rest/services/OdbcWeb/MapServer/1

I've managed to get the JSON of it though the REST, but it only allows 1000 at a time. And there is over 100000 items.

Anyone know any other methods to get this dataset.

Always GIS-ing  ;)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In QGIS try

```
https://gis.co.sangamon.il.us/arcgis/rest/services/TaxParcel/MapServer/28
```

Total Feature Count 105,067

(this matches the data from your url exactly)

[image]

Comment: Nice! how did you find out that url ?

Comment: googled sangamon rest services.

Comment: Ahh, so okay. How about this one ? https://www.kansasgis.org/dot/proxy.jsp?https://services.kgs.ku.edu/arcgis10/rest/services/forka10/KS_Parcels_ORKA/MapServer
It's from here https://www.kansasgis.org/orka/map.cfm

Comment: @AdamGIS Please ask a sperate question - in line with GIS SE guidelines. https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask